# Angular Js call multiple times controller method and display output in view

Tags: angularjs

I am very new to angular js and trying to fetch results from a service in loop and want to show in View.

I believe the flow will be:
View calls controller with last got entry (controller shouldn't know user want to view more data or not so view will control when to stop.). Controller will be calling a service/factory to retrieve the results.

Please suggest if the workflow is correct or I'm mixing view with controller work. Or somehow I believe controller should control logic for how much data has to be collected and just update some local variable with it. View should use that variable to reflect it on view side.

Second thing: How I can retrieve results from Controller in loop from View.

Edit:
How I can get persons values from controller:

If i want to get persons from this controller. How should i ? I'm doing something wrong here. I am not sure if I should call methods from view?

```
angular.module('app.dashboard.dashboardControllers', []).
        controller('dashboardController', ['$scope',
            function ($scope) {

                $scope.persons = $scope.showAssets(null);
                $scope.showAssets = function (lastExecutedId) {
                    var persons_1 = [{
                            "id": 860,
                            "firstName": "Superman",
                            "lastName": "Yoda"
                        }, {
                            "id": 870,
                            "firstName": "Foo",
                            "lastName": "Whateveryournameis"
                        }, {
                            "id": 590,
                            "firstName": "Toto",
                            "lastName": "Titi"
                        }, {
                            "id": 803,
                            "firstName": "Luke",
                            "lastName": "Kyle"
                        }];
                    return persons_1;
                };
            }
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your flow is correct: View -> Controller -> Service = Results last stored in Service

Second Thing: To get results from the view, such as user input elements, those elements need to be bound to some `$scope` inside the controller.

The power of Angular is you will never need to call for these values once you bind them correctly. Your view will always reflect the current values of `$scope` objects or whatever else has a bind on it.

Look this page for descriptions on the popular ways to bind elements:
http://www.javabeat.net/angularjs-ng-model-ng-bind/